# Insert multiple checkboxes into table column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for documents and part of that is the docs being assigned to a category. The table for doc_list looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `doc_list` (
`doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_content` text NOT NULL,
  `doc_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `doc_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_no` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 AUTO_INCREMENT=122 ;
```

I am having to manually assign the cat_no (which is the category ID) but want it to be apart of my doc form submission:

```
    <form action="actions/newDocAdd.php" method="post" id="rtf" name="">
        <input type="text" name="doc_title" id="doc_title" required="required" placeholder="Document Title"/><br />


        <?php 

        try{
            $results = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cat_list ORDER BY cat_title ASC  ");

        }catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }

        $docs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($docs as $docs){  

        echo '

              <input type="checkbox" name="cat_no" value="2" id="cat_no">'.$docs["cat_title"].'<br><br>

            ';}
        ?>

        <textarea name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
                <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="width:100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>

<br><br> 
<input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Create Document" name="submit"/>

        </form>
```

Now it shows me the categories and displays them as checkboxes but because some documents can be apart of more than one category i want to tick the boxes and submit them to the database.

Here is the category table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cat_list` (
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_title` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: Can a doc have multiple categories?  If so, you should have a doc_categories table.

Comment: it works as it is - I jus need a way of making sure the checkboxes submit the id from which one(s) you tick into the cat_no column in the doc_list table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming documents can have multiple categories:**

First you need to group the checkboxes into an array.  You can do this by using the same name with brackets.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cat_no[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cat_no[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cat_no[]" value="3" />
```

Now when you submit the form, `$_POST['cat_no']` will be an array containing the checked values.

For proper database normalization, you need a new table called something like 'doc_category'.  In this table, you would have a composite key of 'doc_id' and 'cat_id':

```
doc_id  | cat_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
```

This signifies that doc_id 1 belongs to the categories 1, 2, and 3.

The relationship from documents to categories is called a many-to-many relationship which in databases, requires a third table (intermediate).

Comment: How do I show the many to many relationship or call in that data because currently I do this: $results = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM doc_list WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, cat_no)");

Comment: Ok, I made the amendments to the first part but when I post the form the datatype is a TEXT column but its just says the word 'Array' when the data is posted from the form?

Comment: @phpcoder, you need to use a JOIN to select data from two tables.  Research more on SQL JOIN syntaxes.   You can't insert an array, you have to loop through it and insert each category into the doc_category table.